# emscripten canvas and main loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, emscripten

How does `emscripten_set_canvas_size` know which canvas to resize when I have mutiple of them in my HTML file, What can I do in that case?
Why can there only be one `emscripten_set_main_loop`, what if want 2 loops one for rendering and another for physics, in javascript I would use `requestAnimationFrame` and `setInterval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emscripten_set_canvas_size` sets the size of the Emscripten canvas, that is, the canvas returned by the `Module.canvas` method of the `Module` object that Emscripten uses.

I know of no way that one Emscripten run time can support multiple canvases or that an active canvas can be changed once Emscripten is initialised. However, it is possible to have multiple Emscripten run times in the same Document, each using it's own canvas. To do this use the `emcc` compile options

```
-s MODULARIZE=1 -s EXPORT_NAME="some_export_name"
```

After doing this, a modularized Emscripten run-time can be instantiated in JavaScript like this:

```
some_export_name(OptionsModule);
```

where `OptionsModule` is the `Module` object that the Emscripten run-time will use. This can be done multiple times with different `Module` objects, typically these different objects would return different canvas HTML elements in their `Module.canvas` methods. An example of this modularization can be found [here](http://lyceum-allotments.github.io/2016/08/emscripten-image-viewer/).

That only one Emscripten main loop can be run is just a design constraint. Two loops can be simulated by calling one function for rendering and one for physics inside the main loop handler. To call these with different intervals it is quite simple to keep track of the timing yourself (using `SDL_GetTicks`).